# nektos/act - local github runner, how to reference local Platform (-P) image without needing docker.io

Tags: python, docker, nektos-act

How to run a local or non-docker image using nektos/act?

Nektos act by default attempts to login to docker.io to pull a remote image, is it possible to use a locally cached image?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem, and so I'll post it with an answer.

The TLDR is `--pull=false` along with the `-P` platform flag will allow you to use a local image.

In my case I'm using a custom python image which was built locally called `python-3.10:latest` but you'd build your own local image using `docker build . -f Dockerfile.python310 -t python-3.10:latest`

To verify a local image use `docker image ls`, also you might need to make sure the architectures match (if the platform doesn't match, it won't find it, but it's probably fine if you're linux/amd64)

I'll try to work through the steps:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}' python-3.10:latest
linux/amd64
```

to debug:

```
gh act -s GITHUB_TOKEN="$(gh auth token)" -P python-3.10=localhost/python-3.10:latest -v --no-skip-checkout --pull=false
```

** make sure to use a very recent version of `gh` the github.com/cli/cli which supports `auth token`.  You might need to replace your distro version which isn't updated as often!